# addClassRules() to multiple fields but only allow 1 at a minimum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

So I have 10 checkbox fields, more then 1 can be selected, but at least 1 has to be selected at a minimum.

I had it working use the `name=""` attribute but that was not the case anymore as the name has to be unique to integrate with our CRM.

So I added the rule to use the class instead using addClassRule() and I added my own method to use a custom message for required.

But the result is they are all required. regardless if 1 or more is selected?

Here is my jQuery which is working but it requires all 10 checkbox's to be checked.

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkboxRequired", $.validator.methods.required, "Please select at least 1 of the values");
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('checkbox-validate', {
    checkboxRequired: true
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="id_1" class="form-input">
    <label for="test1"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test1" name="test1" value="1">1</label>
    <label for="test2"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test2" name="test2" value="2">2</label>
    <label for="test3"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test3" name="test3" value="3">3</label>
    <label for="test4"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test4" name="test4" value="4">4</label>
    <label for="test5"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test5" name="test5" value="5">5</label>
    <label for="test6"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test6" name="test6" value="6">6</label>
    <label for="test7"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test7" name="test7" value="7">7</label>
    <label for="test8"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test8" name="test8" value="8">8</label>
    <label for="test9"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test9" name="test9" value="9">9</label>
    <label for="test10"><input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test10" name="test10" value="10">10</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't... not sure what you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [require_from_group-method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/) rule

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery.validator.addClassRules('checkbox-validate', {
    require_from_group: [1, ".checkbox-validate"]
  });

  var validator = $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {},
    messages: {},
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.hasClass('checkbox-validate')) {
        element.closest('.form-input').find('.error-holder').html(error)
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform" method="post" action="">

  <div id="id_1" class="form-input">
    <label for="test1">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test1" name="test1" value="1" />1</label>
    <label for="test2">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test2" name="test2" value="2" />2</label>
    <label for="test3">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test3" name="test3" value="3" />3</label>
    <label for="test4">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test4" name="test4" value="4" />4</label>
    <label for="test5">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test5" name="test5" value="5" />5</label>
    <label for="test6">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test6" name="test6" value="6" />6</label>
    <label for="test7">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test7" name="test7" value="7" />7</label>
    <label for="test8">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test8" name="test8" value="8" />8</label>
    <label for="test9">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test9" name="test9" value="9" />9</label>
    <label for="test10">
      <input class="checkbox-validate" type="checkbox" id="test10" name="test10" value="10" />10</label>
    <span class="error-holder"></span>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is okay but it then displays an error on each input when I only need an error to display once for all inputs

Comment: should there be a semicolon at the end of the html(error) ?

Comment: @c.had1990 yes... you can add it

Comment: Okay it works, the reason why mine was not working is I was using jQuery validate 1.9 and you used 1.13, what has changed in this scenario since then that has caused mine to just break my jQuery?

Comment: looks like the rule require_from_group is added in a later version

Comment: yeah cool thanks heaps for this, probably why it could not get it to work initially working with a older version. appreciate the help

Comment: @c.had1990 to make your older version work try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/82t4b6j0/3/

Comment: The `require_from_group` method contained bugs that were fixed in a later version.

Answer (score -2):

You need to make your name attribute all be the same value. Then you can check how many are checked like so:

`var count = $('input[name=test]:checked').size();`

Comment: as I said before, I did that and it worked perfectly fine but that is not the case anymore because I need to have them unique to parse values in to our CRM

Comment: Yea, so apply the same concept that I mentioned above like this: `var count = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').size();`